# PopViewController not releasing variables from memory- swift

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management

Im going from a listing page to detail page. In detail page i used to have a array that will change according to user interactions. when coming back to listing page and going again to the detail page doesn't releases my array. I m wondering if so my all poped viewcontrollers will be there and is memory consuming.

my array declaration

```
var relationNamesArray : [String] = []
```

Im poping out

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Actually when my viewcontroller is getting deallocated from memory?

Comment: Maybe somewhere you're keeping reference to that view controller? It should be deallocated after executing `popViewController(:)`.

Comment: what type of reference do you mean? i used to have a protocol inside my detail viewcontroller is't the problem?

Comment: Reference to the PopViewController object.

Comment: try to use `autoreleasepool` on the code you want to be released on priority. It worked for me on a code I had written.

Comment: @Raymound No i doesn't have such refrence.  listing page is just passing a value then detail page is poping out

Comment: Try what @CoderFrom94 suggested, if you read on memory management in Swift, you'll find that garbage collection is not always immediate, and if you need it to be so for some reason, you need to use `autoreleasepool`. However, some more code would be helpful to ensure that you haven't created a retain cycle somewhere